# The operator '[]=' isn't defined for the type 'String'

Tags: dart

I'm getting an error in this code:

```
void main() {
  List<String> wave(String str) {
    List<String> results = [];
    String newStr;
    int i = 0;
    for (String ltr in str.split('')) {
      newStr = str;
      if (ltr != ' ') {
        newStr[i] = ltr.toUpperCase();
        results.add(newStr);
      }
      i++;
    }
    return results;
  }

  print(wave('   gap   '));
}
```

the error is at the line:

```
newStr[i] = ltr.toUpperCase;
```

Despite when I try `print(newStr[i]);` I don't get an error and the code is executed correctly!

Comment: Also, try: `var newStr = str.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r"(?<= |^)[a-z]"), (m) => m[0]!.toUpperCase());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dart String operation, `operator[]` returns a string. Which means, array[index] is used for getting the string in the `index` position. That is why you're getting that error, because you can't set at specific index using this `operator[]` in dart. See the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/operator_get.html) for details.

To replace at the specific index in dart, you can use [replaceFirst(Pattern from, String to, [int startIndex = 0])](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/replaceFirst.html) as the other answer mentioned. Or, you can use [substring(int start, [int? end])](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/substring.html) as follows:

```
  if (ltr != ' ' && i < newStr.length) {
    newStr = newStr.substring(0, i) + ltr.toUpperCase() + newStr.substring(i+1);
    results.add(newStr);
  }
```

To make the code bug free, I've added the checking of the value of `i` in it. You should add the checking to avoid out of bound access.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

`newStr[i] = ltr.toUpperCase();`

to

`newStr = newStr.replaceFirst(ltr,ltr.toUpperCase(),i);`

So the result will be `[   Gap   ,    gAp   ,    gaP   ]`

Honestly, I don't know how `char` is defined in Dart, but I think accessing index of String is kind of getter, thus cannot be set to a new value.